# Is $R(\cdot, V)V : T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$ always self-adjoint?

Tags: differential-geometry

In [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01390161), Ziller states that some calculations that he does to compute the jacobi fields don't require that the globally symmetric space $M$ be compact.

It seems to me that he is using the fact that the map $R(\cdot, V)V : T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$ for fixed $V$ is self-adjoint. The fact is: I managed to prove this under the hypothesis that $M$ is compact by using a biinvariant metric and the formula for the curvature on a globally symmetric space (namely, $R(X,Y)=-\text{ad}[X,Y]$). Since he explicitly states that $M$ does not need to be compact, I think that I may be overlooking something.

Therefore, my questions ar: Is the map $R(\cdot, V)V : T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$ always self-adjoint?

If not, how can one guarantee the existence of those eigenvectors/eigenvalues that he states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $A(\cdot ) = R(\cdot, V)V$. Then

$$\langle A(X), Y\rangle = \langle R(X, V)V, Y\rangle = \langle R (Y, V)V, X\rangle = \langle A(Y), X\rangle.$$

Where we used only

$$R(X, Y)Z = -R(Y, X)Z, \ \ \langle R(X, Y)Z, W\rangle = \langle R(Z, W)X, Y\rangle.$$

Thus $A$ is always self-adjoint.

Comment: Why does the last equality hold?

Comment: There are one of the usual symmetries that is processed by $R$, see here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Symmetries_and_identities (You can check this by using the definition of $R$) @AloizioMacedo